# Java for loop to count up output

Tags: java, arrays, counting

I have a working code but my output doesn't count up.
Here is the code I am working with:

```
for(Course course : courses) {
        for(int i=0;i<1;i++) {
        System.out.println("[" + (i+1) + "]" + course.getCode() + "(" + course.getCreditHour() + ")");
    }

    }
    System.out.print("Enter your choice : ");
```

I need the (i+1) to count from one to 7.

Here is a copy of the output I currently get:

```
Please type the number inside the [] to register for a course
The number inside the () is the credit hours for the course
[1]IT1006(6)
[1]IT4782(3)
[1]IT4789(3)
[1]IT4079(6)
[1]IT2230(3)
[1]IT3345(3)
[1]IT2249(6)
Enter your choice :
```

I need the numbers inside the square brackets to count from 1 to 7.

This is for an academic assignment.

Comment: Think about `int i=0; i<1` in the loop. Did you intend to have a 1 there?

Comment: If i put more than 1 there it repeats the loop and prints each selection the number of times I put in there.

Answer (score 2):

Your inner loop isn't doing anything. There's no point in using a loop if you've hard coded it to just run once.

I'd get rid of your outer loop and just index `courses` directly:

```
for(int i = 0; i < courses.size(); i++){
    Course course = courses.get(i);
    System.out.println("[" + (i+1) + "]" + course.getCode() + "(" + course.getCreditHour() + ")");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for(Course course : courses) means  : for each course so i is reinitialised you whant a variable that will be increment on each iteration so the variable must be declared outside the block. you can write some thing like this :

```
int i = 1;
for(Course course : courses) {
    System.out.println("[" + (i++) + "]" + course.getCode() + "(" + course.getCreditHour() + ")");
}    
System.out.print("Enter your choice : ");
```

the method of @Carcigenicate will work too but can handle so performance issue if you use linked structure as linkedlist tthis will become for an Array :

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < courses.lenght ; i++){
    System.out.println("[" + i + "]" + courses[i].getCode() + "(" + courses[i].getCreditHour() + ")");
}
System.out.print("Enter your choice : ");
```

and on collections :

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < courses.getSize(); i++){
    System.out.println("[" + i + "]" + courses.get(i).getCode() + "(" + courses.get(i).getCreditHour() + ")");
}
System.out.print("Enter your choice : ");
```

Comment: That did it.  I never thought about moving the variable outside the loop then just using the simple addition method to get what I was after.  Thanks for the assistance.